# form is displaying again on screen after passing value to php code using ajax

Tags: php, html, ajax, forms, scripting

I was trying to send data from html form to  PHP code that compare the value selected with some info in database and get the result back to be displayed... so far, I got everything working and the data displayed correctly.The problem is that when i get the result i get the drop down box displayed again below the first one.

I actually separated them in two files d.php and form.html(which includes the form and ajax code) it actually worked perfectly that way. but I'm actually trying to get all the code in one php file. Here my code:

```
mysql_select_db("");


    $q = intval($_GET['q']);


      if($q=='6000'){

          $getrow= "SELECT  ProdPrice WHERE ProdID = 6000";
                $list = mysql_query($getrow, $...) or die(mysql_error());
                $rs = mysql_fetch_assoc($list);
                $totalRows_list = mysql_num_rows($list);
                echo $rs['ProdPrice'];



      }



?>


 <html>
<head>

<script>
function showUser(str) {
  if (str=="") {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
    return;
  } 
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {

    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else { 
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=this.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","?q="+str,true);
  xmlhttp.send();

}
</script>
</head>
<body>


<form>
<select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
<option value="">Select a person:</option>
<option value="6000">15</option>
<option value="2">n</option>
<option value="3">n</option>
<option value="4">e</option>
</select>
</form>
<br>
<div id="txtHint"></b></div>
</br>
</body>
</html>

                    [before submitting form value][1]

[after selecting the value][1]
```

Comment: Don't use the `mysql_*` functions. They have been deprecated since v5.5 (Jun 2013) and removed since v7.0 (Dec 2015). Instead use the [**mysqli_***](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) functions with [**prepared statements**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) and [**bound parameters**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php).

Comment: yes I will change it. Any suggestions about what I asked tho? @AlexHowansky

Comment: Could you please highlight what's your PHP file content and what's the HTML files content? As of now, it seems that all your code is already written into a single file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there's nothing wrong actually. When the server is done executing the PHP code, it'll continue reading the HTML content and send it to the browser.

To fix it, add this line before the ending brace of your if condition `if($q=='6000'){` in the PHP code:

```
exit();
```

Also, as Alex commented, do use `mysqli_*` functions. `mysql_*`is now deprecated hence vulnerable to security threats.

Comment: You're welcome! Regarding mysqli functions, you can check out this link for more info: https://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_ref_mysqli.asp

Comment: One more question, I'm actually adding an item to cart so that would be a problem with the exit() because it is not going to continue the php code until the end. as a result,  I won't be redirected to 'shopping cart'. is there anything that can be done to solve that? @jash101

Comment: @user8237728 The add to cart function should be implemented by javascript, so that even if user goes offline for a brief period, his cart items are not messed up. You should pass on the cart info to the server only during checkout. That's what all major e-commerce companies do...

Comment: the thing is that I didn't build this website. I'm just trying to add the dropdown functionality to it. and now after modifying the code and adding the exit() function to it it's not continuing to the php code below it in which binding sql columns to add to cart after that. So I got the drop down working perfectly but when I press the add to cart button it does nothing. @ jash101